# How to style javascript output?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have made a plugin for my website using javascript, one line of the code is output.innerHTML = "Test";

Can I style this using CSS or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I style this using CSS

Yes. Write a selector that matches the element you have a reference to in `output`.

Alternatively, add new elements inside it and write selectors that match them.

> or is there another way?

Not anything sane.

Comment: And now I want to see all the *insane* ways you know how to style elements... :)

Comment: JSSS, presentational HTML and hiding them off-screen before rendering them on a canvas element spring to mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can write directly like this

```
output.innerHTML = "<p style='your styles'>Test</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the text which is appended to the `output` element, then either apply a CSS class or edit the style via javascript, for example by doing the following:

```
output.style.color = "#FF0000";
```

which would produce red text.

Comment: As would `'#f00'` and `'red'` (not criticism, just adding further information).

Answer (score -1):

the html

```
<html>
    <body>
      <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  console.log(output);
  output.innerHTML = "test";
  output.style.color ="#ff0000";
};
```

will do the work. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/FszHr)

Be noted to always use `window.onload` or `$(document).ready(function(){})` for the jQuery equivalence to make sure that the DOM element has exist by the time your javascript code is being executed.

Comment: Thanks for that I have tried out a few methods mentioned here but have decided to style using #output in a separate css file. I wondered what windows.onload is about as have seen it a few times thanks for explaining what it does!

Comment: `window.onload` waits for the HTML element to be exist (and all images) in the page before the code executes. This prevents you from getting the `undefined` or `null` value from `document.getElementById('output')`. [READMORE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/js-window-onload-vs-jquery-document-ready)